# How can I catch intents of running or launched apps using Bcast receivers

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to catch intents of currently running applications, I have tried using ACTION_MAIN but it doesn't work, any other way to receive intents of running apps or launched apps ??

Basically I want to receive that currently running app if found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I catch intents of running or launched apps using Bcast receivers

There are no such broadcasts.

> any other way to receive intents of running apps or launched apps

No.